# update speed temp table versus table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

Update of temp table is slowed down by logging on update. Will the same logging happen on a table variable ? Is there a way to prevent this logging to speed up updates on a large table. For exemple in an ETL, you dont need rollback capability.

Comment: What is the "logging"? If you mean a transaction log then info about any transaction will be stored into the transaction log. Either you update a temp table or a temp variable, whatever.

Comment: Right, I mean transaction log.

Comment: An option is in-memory User-Defined Table Types, which are essentially in-memory temp table variables with memory optimization enhancements. You would need to alter database for memory optimization, create a filegroup, and create the user-defined table type in advance.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/faster-temp-table-and-table-variable-by-using-memory-optimization?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trx logs are not applied to table variables, and also no statistics generated for table variables. So it depends on how you use the table variables whether they perform better or not than temp tables. And NO, you can't disable trx logging for tables or temp tables in SQL server. You can change database option to BULK Logged for better logging performance, however it will affect all the tables in the db and it has some implications for the db recovery. Unless the db is purely for ETL, it is not recommended.

Comment: If it is true that Trx logs are not applied to table variables, then I can possibly make my ETL much faster by using table variables instead of temp tables. This ETL does lots of updates to large temp tables, and this is much more time consumming than it should. I'll post numeric resuts if I can do a parallel run...